# Remove the checkbox when deleting an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, checkbox

There is a problem with the code:

1. if I select elements, they are added to the `.selected-items` block; if I remove the checkbox in the upper row of elements, the elements disappear in the lower row but I want this to work in both directions, what would the element be when I click on the checkbox in the lower row disappeared from the bottom row and removed the checkbox from the corresponding element in the top row.
2. I have a condition under which if there are more than 4 elements in the bottom row, an alert appears and the element is not added to the list, but the checkbox remains, how to cancel it if an alert appears?

Here is a code example.

https://codepen.io/annbin/pen/VwYRerL

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix the first issue you need to pass the event object the the `click` callback function, and prevent the event if there are more than 4 items selected:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
   if($('.selected-items .sample-item-wrapper').length > 3) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

For the second issue you need to uncheck the matching checkbox inside the `.samples-items-wrapper`:

```
$("div.samples-items-wrapper div[data-sample-id='"+selected_item+"']").find(':checkbox').prop("checked", false);
```

Here is a working example with the changes that I made to your original snippet:

```js
    $(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
        if($(this).prop("checked") === true){
            if($('.selected-items .sample-item-wrapper').length > 3) {
                alert('4 item max');
              e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                $(".selected-items").append(($(this).closest(".sample-item-wrapper").clone()));
                $(".selected-items .sample-item-wrapper").attr("style","");
            }
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") === false){
            var selected_item = $(this).closest(".sample-item-wrapper").attr('data-sample-id');
            $("div.selected-items div[data-sample-id='"+selected_item+"']").remove();
            $("div.samples-items-wrapper div[data-sample-id='"+selected_item+"']").find(':checkbox').prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
```

```css
.samples-items-wrapper, .selected-items {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="samples-items-wrapper">
    <div data-sample-id="sample-21" class="sample-item-wrapper">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
        <div class="pretty p-default">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="state">
                <label>1</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-sample-id="sample-22" class="sample-item-wrapper">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
        <div class="pretty p-default">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="state">
                <label>2</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-sample-id="sample-23" class="sample-item-wrapper">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
        <div class="pretty p-default">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="state">
                <label>3</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div data-sample-id="sample-24" class="sample-item-wrapper">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
        <div class="pretty p-default">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="state">
                <label>4</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div data-sample-id="sample-25" class="sample-item-wrapper">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
        <div class="pretty p-default">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="state">
                <label>5</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="selected-items"></div>
```

Comment: Could you see something else?
I want to add - instead of input - cross so that it would be clear. that you can click on it and delete the item, but there is a bug there, could you please also see this task, please?
I updated the code by adding your code there and my condition in else

https://codepen.io/annbin/pen/VwYRerL
im add 
`$(".selected-items .sample-item-wrapper .pretty").remove();`
`$(".selected-items .sample-item-wrapper").append('<div class="cross"></div');`

Comment: You helped me a lot with this example, thank you very much, I just hope you can help with one more, if not, I understand)

Comment: @annkarsksya Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yfq1e57/)

Comment: Thanks) really helped me)